# Free Web Host Service *Without* Web Builder?

Tags: html, web, build, host

I found a few web hosting services that look great (e.g. Google Sites, Wix, etc.) but none seem to allow to just upload an HTML file, rather than *embed* HTML code in a website that was created using the provided web builders.
Anyone know of a web hosting service that allows to just upload complete pre-coded HTML files rather than having to go through a web builder? Or is it possible with the two websites I mentioned above?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Learn how to use `Github` in general, and then more specifically, `Github Pages`.

Comment: @kojow7 Thank you. I'll look into it. I did start using an FTP server to upload HTML to infinityfree.net/ and it works pretty well too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

1. https://000webhost.com/
2. https://www.netlify.com/
3. https://pages.github.com/

Or if you work with framework such as React or Flask for Python web, you can use https://www.heroku.com/. It's free and you can even host your website through repository on your Github.